# ajax form not submitting post

Tags: php, ajax, forms, post, json

I have created a form using ajax, which posts the data as a json array, to a seperate php file. The markup ajax for posting the form to the php handler is:

```
$.ajax({
   dataType: "json",
   type: "post",
   url: "ajax.php?action=add_driver",
   data: $("form#addDriver").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
   beforeSend: function()
   {

$('.error, .success, .notice').remove();

},
success: function(json)
{

if (json['status']=='success'){
    alert(json['message']);
    }else{

if(json['error']['driver_firstname']){
    $("input[name=driver_firstname]").after('<div class="error">'+json['error'['driver_firstname']+'</div>');   
}

if(json['error']['driver_surname']){
    $("input[name=driver_surname]").after('<div class="error">'+json['error']['driver_surname']+'</div>');  
}
if(json['error']['driver_dob']){
    $("input[name=driver_dob]").after('<div class="error">'+json['error']['driver_dob']+'</div>');  
}

if(json['error']['driver_address']){
    $("input[name=driver_address]").after('<div class="error">'+json['error']['driver_address']+'</div>');  
}

if(json['error']['driver_postcode']){
    $("input[name=driver_postcode]").after('<div class="error">'+json['error']['driver_postcode']+'</div>');    
}

if(json['error']['driver_city']){
    $("input[name=driver_city]").after('<div class="error">'+json['error']['driver_city']+'</div>');    
}

if(json['error']['driver_county']){
    $("input[name=driver_county]").after('<div class="error">'+json['error']['driver_county']+'</div>');    
}

if(json['error']['driver_email']){
    $("input[name=driver_email]").after('<div class="error">'+json['error']['driver_email']+'</div>');  
}

if(json['error']['driver_tel']){
    $("input[name=driver_tel]").after('<div class="error">'+json['error']['driver_tel']+'</div>');  
}

if(json['error']['driver_mobile']){
    $("input[name=driver_mobile]").after('<div class="error">'+json['error']['driver_mobile']+'</div>');    
}   

//These are the series of validation checks carried out before submission//


}
                     });
```

This is passed to the file named in the url, ajax.php, which checks for errors, using the php validation, and if all is ok, is supposed to insert into the database. The coding markup for this part is:

```
<?php
$json = array();


if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {

//for the first field only//            
$driver_firstname = tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_POST_VARS['driver_firstname']);

if (strlen($driver_firstname)<4){
  $json['error']['driver_firstname'] = 'First Name is required!';
}

if (isset($json['error']) and !empty($json['error'])){

    $json['status'] = 'error';
    $json['message'] = 'Please check your error(s)!';

}else{


     $sql_data_array = array('driver_firstname' => $driver_firstname);

     tep_db_perform(TABLE_DRIVERS, $sql_data_array);

     $driver_id = tep_db_insert_id();

     $json['status'] = 'success';
     $json['message'] = 'Data has been successfully updated!';
    }

}

     echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

For some reason, it is not posting any of the values to the php file from the browser, and is showing a blank array. When I use the 'get' type, it works. Can anyone help to tell me why it is not working for the 'post' type? If the ajax.php part is required, please let me know...

Comment: I have a feeling, .serialze actually attaches the data to the URL, and not into a JSON object.

Comment: You appear to be asking why some PHP code *that you haven't shown us* doesn't work. That isn't something we can really tell you.

Comment: @Quentin...do you want me to post the coding for the php handler?

Comment: Do your form element all have name attributes in the HTML markup? This would cause an empty array/json object if they did not, and ID doesn't count. It's noted in the jQuery documentation that this is required. Need to see more of your code to know for sure. HTML and PHP would help. http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize

Comment: i have added the coding for the php handler, showing only the first field...

Comment: its working for the `GET` method, but not for post, but `GET` isn't very secure...anyone know why post doesn't work?

Comment: Well for one, I've only ever retrieved `POST` data in PHP from an AJAX call with `$_POST['myVariable']`.  Second `.serialize()` just encodes a url string such as, `driver_firstname=name`.  So you can't just assign it an error and access it that way.  Look at the API, it shows the string that is created with `.serialize()`.  It's probably working with `GET` because `GET` can access cached sources.

Answer (score 1):

[`$HTTP_POST_VARS` is deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) (you should have stopped using it over *eleven years ago*) and a quick test with it on my copy of PHP failed to get it to work. Use `$_POST`.

Answer (score 1):

Use .serializeArray() instead of .serialize to do what you want.

http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Sample Result:

`[{name: "a", value: "1"  }, {name: "b", value: "2"  }, {name: "c", value: "3"}, {name: "d", value: "4"  }, {name: "e", value: "5"  }]`

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Sample Result:

`a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=5`

Code should look closer to this.  Use `.done` and catch return data in the function.

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "ajax.php?action=add_driver", 
    dataType: "json",
    date:  $("form#addDriver").serializeArray(),
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('.error, .success, .notice').remove();
    }
}).done(function(json) {
    if (json['status']=='success'){
        alert(json['message']);
    }else{
        if(json['error']['driver_surname']){
           /* Do Stuff */ 
        }
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$myData = array();
$json = array();

if(isset($_POST['yourData'])){
    $myData = $_POST['yourData'];
}

/* Do stuff */
$json['myValue'] = $myData['passedValue']; 


echo json_encode($json);
?>
```